# Present or Past when talking about a book's content

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I came across an English exercise yesterday and I wasn't sure about the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. The sentence is as follows:

I borrowed a book from the library last week. It  ______(be) about Wright Brothers.

Just wonder should the answer be 'was' or 'is' since the content of the book doesn't change over time.

Comment: DO use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). DO NOT use them for minor edits ([edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) instead) answers (post an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebukes ([vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) instead), discussion ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), or comments on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead).

Comment: *I borrowed a book from the library last week. It ______(be) about Wright Brothers* has two problems.

If *It ______(be)* is meant to indicate the gap should be filled by a form of the verb *to be*, someone should have said so.

Then *Wright Brothers* needed the missing article, *the*. Who dropped that, please?

If either of those mistakes was the exercise’s, consider seeking better sources.

After all that, whether the content of the book changes over time doesn’t matter here. You borrowed the book in the past tense and in the same way it *was*, not *is* about the Wright Brothers.